# Can we replace group by or for loop with another logic in Python

Tags: python-3.x, performance, for-loop

I have a customer email dataset containing information on various aspects like:

[image: email data]

I have written following function to calculate date difference for emails where PropertyNo match.

```
def occurence3(df):
    for ind, row in df.iterrows(): 
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime((df['Date']),format='%m/%d/%y') 
        df['Diff'] = df.groupby('PropertyNo').Date.diff(-1).abs().dt.days 
    return df
```

can we replace group by/for loop with some other logic to speed up code execution.

Comment: Adding as a comment, since I am not a Numpy expert, but it looks like you are doing a GroupBy on the whole data set in every iteration. Each GroupBy requires you to iterate over the whole set. Instead of nested grouping sort the data by property number and date before iterating and you should see substantial speedup.

Comment: I like your advice @NickBailey. But the data also contains many premises number which do not repeat. Even if I sort data sequentially and remove nested group by it would give me incorrect results.